# Possible to set custom colors for Ext.JS graph legends

Tags: extjs

One of my recent project i need to set some custom color to my graph legends[image: Sample image] .

Is it possible to set custom color. If possible how can i change that.

Comment: yes, it is possible, could you share some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your chart series config, you can defined your own `renderer` function (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Column-cfg-renderer). In this function you can change column attributes.

So if you want to change columns color, renderer function should look like this:

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
    var value = 0;
    if (index > 0) {
        value = index % 2;
    }
    var color = ['#5B96CD', '#D0D0D0'][value];
    return Ext.apply(attr, {
        fill: color
    });
}
```

See fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25k

Comment: This does not change the LEGEND COLOR. if you doubt that you can go to you link and set **legend: true**